# Getting document.getElementsByName from another page PHP/javascript

Tags: javascript, php

so i have been looking around on how to do this but with no success.
Im trying to get the value of the name test from an external website

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="ThisIsAValue" />
```

But so far i have only found how to get the value of that with an ID

```
<input type="hidden" id="test" name="test" value="ThisIsAValue" autocomplete="off" />
```

but I need to try find it without a ID is my problem. 
And this is an example on how to get it from the ID

```
<?php

$doc = new DomDocument;

$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->loadHtml(file_get_contents('http://example.com/bla.php'));

var_dump($doc->getElementById('test'));

?>
```

And i have found how to get it from name and NOT ID on the same page

```
<script>
function getElements()
{
var test = document.getElementsByName("test")[0].value;
alert(test);
}
</script>
```

But again I dont know how to get the value of it by name from an external page eg "http://example.com/bla.php", any help?

Thanks

Comment: Your second code is JavaScript whereas your first one is PHP. Do you want to adapt the JS solution to PHP?

Comment: I dont mind, either way

Comment: I've written an answer. You cannot load an external file in JavaScript (unless the external server sends CORS headers). JavaScript also runs on the client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/domdocument) doesn't have a method `getElementsByName()`. I would suggest collecting all inputs first and then manually filtering them.

```
$inputs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('input');
$testInput = null;

foreach ($inputs as $input) {
  if ($input->getAttribute('name') === 'test') {
    $testInput = $input;
    break;
  }
}

if (!$testInput) {
  exit('There was an error. input[name="test"] could not be found.');
}

// otherwise dump the input!
var_dump($testInput);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, How would i echo each of them out after that? "echo $input;" or somthing? because all i can get it to do is echo out "1"